# Maven Shade Plugin not including resources of dependency

Tags: maven, resources, dependencies, maven-shade-plugin

I'm using the Maven Shade Plugin to include all dependencies during package phase.
That works fine for classes, but dependent resources aren't included.

Here's the layout of the dependent jar:

```
./config.properties <-- this is the missing resource
./META-INF
./META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
./META-INF/maven
./META-INF/maven/com.example
./META-INF/maven/com.example/bar
./META-INF/maven/com.example/bar/pom.properties
./META-INF/maven/com.example/bar/pom.xml
```

Here's the shade plugin configuration:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <transformers>
            <transformer
              implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
              <manifestEntries>
                <Main-Class>com.example.foo.Foo</Main-Class>
                <!-- <X-Compile-Source-JDK>${maven.compile.source}</X-Compile-Source-JDK>.
                  <X-Compile-Target-JDK>${maven.compile.target}</X-Compile-Target-JDK> -->
              </manifestEntries>
            </transformer>
          </transformers>
          <filters>
            <filter>
              <!--
                Exclude files that sign a jar
                (one or multiple of the dependencies).
                One may not repack a signed jar without
                this, or you will get a
                SecurityException at program start.
              -->
              <artifact>*:*</artifact>
              <excludes>
                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                <exclude>META-INF/*.INF</exclude> <!-- This one may not be required -->
              </excludes>
            </filter>
          </filters>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: Have you tried with the up-to-date version of [maven-shade-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) and without any configuration.

Comment: I have tested this with a simple multi module project and with version 1.6 and 2.0 of the shade plugin my property files are copied. Could you try to add junit:junit:4.11 (compile scope) as dependency and see if the Licence.txt is copied? If its still not work could you please add your project layout and the complete pom. Thx.

Comment: Yes, the License.txt is copied. I'll add more info.

Comment: It's quite embarrasing, but there was a typo in the version of the dependency and that version didn't have that file :-/ Should I delete this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's embarrasing, but there was a typo in the version of the dependency and that version didn't have the file.